# Does the series $w(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}w_n(x)$ converge uniformly?

Tags: sequences-and-series

*Is the following interpretation correct?*

In my textbook, I stumbled upon the following theorem;

> Suppose that $\{w_n\}$ is a sequence of continuous functions and $w_n : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$. If the series
> $$w(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}w_n(x)$$
> converges **uniformly**, then $w(x)$ is continuous on $\Omega$.

I have two questions as regards this theorem;

A) If I know for sure that $w(x)$ is not completely continuous on $\Omega$ (referring to if there are any jump- or essential discontinuities) and $\{w_n\}$ is a sequence of continuous functions and $w_n : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, do I know if the sum $w(x)$ **does not** converge uniformly?

B) How would an outline for a proof look like?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: A) yes;  B) Check any book on real analysis;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A) Yes: if the sum is not continuous, then the series is not niformly convergent. Essentially  this is the contrapositive statement of the theorem.

B) See the Wikipedia article for the theorem: [click here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_limit_theorem).